# Could Not Convert String To Float In Calculating Moving Average

Tags: string

I'm trying to create a function that calculates a moving average from csv file. However, when I go to run the function Pycharm tells me the main error is that it cannot convert the 'close**' string to float.

How would I go about correcting this? I've understand I must need to cast a string to into a float, but I can't seem to figure out where I need to apply this change.

Here's the code:

```
def csv_to_moving_average(Crypto):
    csv_file = f"{Crypto}.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, names=['Date', 'Open*', 'High', 'Low', 'Close**', 'Volume', 'Market Cap', 'Moving Average'])
    df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    df['Moving Average'] = df['Close**'].rolling(25).mean().plot
    df = df.drop('Market Cap', axis=1)
    df = df.drop('Volume', axis=1)
    df = df.drop('High', axis=1)
    df.plot()
    plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal CSV file that will trigger the error? The chances are that you have values in that column that can't be converted to float. Create a new CSV file by copying the first three rows of the file that is causing the problem, see if that's enough to cause the error.

Comment: Aside: rather than slurping up the entire file and dropping columns, you can specify which columns to read from the file into your data frame: pd.read_csv(csv_file, … , usecols['Date', 'Open*', 'Low', 'Close**', 'Moving Average'])